# Error When Running Server Container : TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '100')

Tags: node.js, containers, typeerror, upgrade

I am trying to run my server container locally and I am getting the following. Not sure where to look.

```
server_1                  | 
server_1                  | > app-crm-lite@0.0.0 start:development
server_1                  | > NODE_ENV=development tsnd -r tsconfig-paths/register --poll --respawn --debug --transpile-only --ignore-watch node_modules app.ts
server_1                  | 
server_1                  | Ignore watch: [ 'node_modules' ]
server_1                  | [INFO] 22:44:38 ts-node-dev ver. 1.1.8 (using ts-node ver. 9.1.1, typescript ver. 4.3.5)
server_1                  | [DEBUG] 22:44:38 Starting child process -r /tmp/ts-node-dev-hook-2642022531538526.js -r tsconfig-paths/register /service/server/node_modules/ts-node-dev/lib/wrap.js app.ts
server_1                  | [DEBUG] 22:44:38 /service/server/app.ts added to watcher
server_1                  | [DEBUG] 22:44:38 /service/server/app.ts compiled in 162 ms
server_1                  | [DEBUG] 22:44:38 /service/server/middleware/common/request-correlation/index.ts added to watcher
server_1                  | [DEBUG] 22:44:38 /service/server/middleware/common/request-correlation/index.ts compiled in 11 ms
server_1                  | TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '100')
server_1                  |     at forEachCode (/service/server/node_modules/http-errors/index.js:261:45)
server_1                  |     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
server_1                  |     at populateConstructorExports (/service/server/node_modules/http-errors/index.js:259:9)
server_1                  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/service/server/node_modules/http-errors/index.js:31:1)
server_1                  |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:14)
server_1                  |     at Module._compile (/service/server/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:568:25)
server_1                  |     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1209:10)
server_1                  |     at require.extensions..jsx.require.extensions..js (/tmp/ts-node-dev-hook-2642022531538526.js:114:20)
server_1                  |     at Object.nodeDevHook [as .js] (/service/server/node_modules/ts-node-dev/lib/hook.js:63:13)
server_1                  |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:32)
server_1                  |     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:868:12)
server_1                  |     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1057:19)
server_1                  |     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
server_1                  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/service/server/node_modules/send/index.js:15:19)
server_1                  |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:14)
server_1                  |     at Module._compile (/service/server/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:568:25)
server_1                  |     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1209:10)
server_1                  |     at require.extensions..jsx.require.extensions..js (/tmp/ts-node-dev-hook-2642022531538526.js:114:20)
server_1                  |     at Object.nodeDevHook [as .js] (/service/server/node_modules/ts-node-dev/lib/hook.js:63:13)
server_1                  |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:32)
server_1                  |     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:868:12)
server_1                  |     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1057:19)
server_1                  | [DEBUG] 22:44:39 Child error
server_1                  | [ERROR] 22:44:39 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '100')
server_1                  | [DEBUG] 22:44:39 Disconnecting from child
server_1                  | [DEBUG] 22:44:39 Sending SIGTERM kill to child pid 25
server_1                  | [DEBUG] 22:44:39 Child exited with code null
```

I have done a node module upgrade and was expecting things to work correctly

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.